# Reusing the database connection used by the doctrine entity manager

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

Doctrine encapsulates the native, driver specific database connection resource handle inside of its Connection classes. I'm talking about the resource returned from, for example, `mysqli_connect()`. I don't see any way to access the raw connection resource - there's no getter methods that I've been able to find. This strong encapsulation should probably be a hint that I shouldn't try to access it, and use it, but of course, that's exactly what I want to do.

**Would it cause any problem if I were to issue read-only select queries from the same connection?** I'm not sure how doctrine's work flow operates under the hood. Database connections are stateful, and I'm a bit scared that I might jump in and issue an sql query at a moment when doctrine has some multi-step transaction partially in progress, and that would obviously cause a problem. But with php's single threaded nature I think there's a decent chance it might not be possible in practice, depending on how doctrine works.

<sub>Aside: The reason I want to do this is for performance. I have some other code that isn't written with doctrine, and it wants a raw database connection because it uses the native db extension functions. I could just open another db connection, but opening a second connection has significant performance implications in my scenario...making it very appealing to try to reuse the doctrines connection.</sub>

Comment: doctrine is meant to abstract the underlying database connection. why would you like to use that? just create a raw connection

Comment: @Aris Did you read the last part of post? I explained why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `getWrappedConnection` it returns instance of `Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection` which is a wrapper for `\PDO`:

```
$connection = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->getConnection()
    ->getWrappedConnection();

$stmt = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM `City`');
$stmt->execute();
```

P.S. I believe it is perfectly normal to reuse an existing connection, instead of creating a new one. I am doing this in a project that has Doctrine1 and Doctrine2.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer not because it directly answers my question, but because of the fact that the public method `getWrappedConnection()` in practice returns implementations which more or less directly use the real connection resource without doing checking of connection/transaction state. This to me, this indicates the developers don't feel such a thing is necessary. So, it appears safe to reuse the raw connection.